# Facebook API get all my Status

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi guys i've searched a lot here on stackoverflow but i'have not find a solution for my problem.
I'm building a (University) project , this project aims to do some operation (like sentiment analysis) on a user statuses.
I'm using Facebook PHP SDK , and after login i can get some of my Statuses with this code :

```
  $request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/statuses'
   );
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
var_dump($graphObject);
```

Now the problem is that with this code, i get something like ~20 of my statuses, and at the very bottom of the response i got the paging links (previous or next) for get ~20 more statuses.
There is a way to get all my posts from the first? Or some trick to get that?
Thanks in Advance Nico.

Comment: No you have to iterate through all pages

Comment: Do you think is possible using an array add first 20 statuses , then with pagination links (dunno how) load other 20 and then add  them to the array , and i keep doing this until i finish. Just an idea

Comment: Yes, that you can do

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question , but i've searched but i havent find a solution, once i get the link for next statuses (ex : https://graph.facebook.com/10203323659185569/statuses?limit=25&since=1411590210&__paging_token=enc_AexEzXuuMq7es3JhGC29Jch40M2VeJ2aqssIO6m3XAW6nrSqo8rizCj_duJ4qRlWezsEgTPXi0H7ZPKq7ytKXAiC).
How can  i use this for another request?